# Using IndexOf() method on a string showing "Not allowed to load local resource" error

Tags: javascript, methods

I'm in early stages of learning Javascript and having a problem with following piece of code. It keeps showing "Not allowed to load local resource" error. Could someone please help resolve it?

Thanks

```
var email = "fsdfds@gmail.co.nz";
for(i = 0; i<email.length; i++) {
if(email.charAt(i) === "@") {
console.log("there is an @ at the index " + i);};
};

var location = email.indexOf("q");
console.log(location);
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable "location" is the problem here. Try changing the variable name.

The variable name "location" refers to [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location).

The window.location API provides information to the browser (or any API consumer attached to the page) about where the browser has currently navigated to. It contains properties such as host (the site - stackoverflow.com), href (the url of the page - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56502232, and the protocol (https:).

When setting the `location` variable, the browser thinks you are trying to navigate to a different page - specifically whatever you're setting it to - and it will attempt to navigate to that location.

In this case, you're setting `location` to `-1`, effectively attempting to browse to the location -1. Since no protocol (such as https://) is specified, Chrome searches locally for the location called -1, and as you'd expect, fails to find it.

You could type in your console `location = https://google.com` to navigate to google.com.